# How to extract data from tag or HTML class using vbscript? Only tags or classes I choose

Tags: vbscript

Can someone help me? I need to extract the texts that are between tags or HTML classes using VBScript and save to a single text file. I need to save the tags or classes I define on different lines.

I've found a lot of code on the internet, but none worked as expected.

For example, I have the code below, but I can't extract classes through it, and it's not possible for more than one tag either. In many cases the code doesn't even work.

```
myURL = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss"

Set oXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set ohtmlFile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8

oXMLHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
oXMLHttp.send

If oXMLHttp.Status = 200 Then

ohtmlFile.Write oXMLHttp.responseText
ohtmlFile.Close

Set oTable = ohtmlFile.getElementsByTagName("description")
sFileName = "c:\users\user\desktop\News.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForAppending, True)
For Each oTab In oTable
    objFile.Write oTab.Innertext & vbCrLf
Next
objFile.Close
End If

WScript.Quit
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression instead, though:

```
Option Explicit
Dim myURL,oXMLHttp,objFSO,Description,write2File,ws
myURL = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss"
set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set oXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oXMLHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
oXMLHttp.send

If oXMLHttp.Status = 200 Then
    Description = Extract(oXMLHttp.responseText)
    Set write2File = objFSO.CreateTextFile(".\News.txt",True)
    write2File.WriteLine(Description)
    write2File.Close
    ws.run ".\News.txt"
End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Extract(Data)  
    Dim re,Match,Matches
     Set re = New RegExp 
     re.Global = True 
     re.IgnoreCase = True  
     re.Pattern = "<description><!\[CDATA\[([\s\S]*?)\]\]><\/description>" 
     Set Matches = re.Execute(Data)
     For Each Match in Matches
         Description = Description & Match.SubMatches(0) & vbCrlf & vbCrlf
     Next  
    Extract = Description
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***EDIT :***

For your second request about how to get news from google :

```
Option Explicit
Dim myURL,oXMLHttp,objFSO,GoogleNews,write2File,ws
myURL = "https://news.google.com/?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en"
set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set oXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
oXMLHttp.Open "GET", myURL, False
oXMLHttp.send

If oXMLHttp.Status = 200 Then
    GoogleNews = Extract(oXMLHttp.responseText)
    Set write2File = objFSO.CreateTextFile(".\GoogleNews.txt",True,-1)
    write2File.WriteLine(GoogleNews)
    write2File.Close
    ws.run ".\GoogleNews.txt"
End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Extract(Data)  
    Dim re,Match,Matches
     Set re = New RegExp 
     re.Global = True 
     re.IgnoreCase = True  
     re.MultiLine = True
     re.Pattern = "(\bclass=""DY5T1d"" >)(.+?)<\/a>" 
     Set Matches = re.Execute(Data)
     For Each Match in Matches
         GoogleNews = GoogleNews & Match.SubMatches(1) & vbCrlf & vbCrlf
     Next  
    GoogleNews = Replace(GoogleNews,"&#39;","'")
    GoogleNews = Replace(GoogleNews,"&quot;",chr(34))
    Extract = GoogleNews
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks @Hackoo, it really helped me... I have one more question and if I wanted to extract the text that is between **'<a>' tag** or the one that has the **"class =" DY5T1d ""** of this webpage (https://news.google.com/?hl=en-US&gl = US & ceid = US: en). What would I have to change in my code? Can you help me?

Comment: It really solved my problem. I am grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with using the [getElementsByTagName Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms765549(v%3Dvs.85)) with your `ohtmlFile` object. You can specify the tag types you want. For example:

```
Set objAnchors = ohtmlFile.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

This returns all `<a>` tags in the HTML document.